# What made Leibniz think about calculus?

Tags: calculus

We know that Sir Isaac Newton thought about calculus when he tried to efficiently describe his physical laws but what made Sir Gottfried Leibniz think about something which we know today as calculus?

Comment: It is a bit strange writing "Sir" with Leibniz.  In English, the title "Sir" before the name goes to those awarded certain honors by the King (or Queen) of England.

Comment: IT IS just a mark of respect

Comment: The sentence which begins with "We know" has no justification. Motivation for calculus came from problems of computation of tangents, areas and such, as far as we can judge from preserved documents. For example, Newton was editing the book of his teacher Barrow on calculus, and this book had nothing to do with physics.

Comment: See [Early History of the calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_calculus#Newton_and_Leibniz)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko this line from above link may provide you justification "Newton provided some of the most important applications to physics, especially of integral calculus. "

Comment: See also [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/when-was-the-inverse-relationship-between-tangents-and-quadrature-area-first-ide) for the history of problems related to the discovery.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza: For me, Wikipedia is not an authority. Show me a text written by Newton, where Calculus (fluxions etc.) is applied to pysics.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Well, Leibniz did assert that he had the title "Freiherr", although it's unproven.